# Data cleaning for duplications within cells of a dataframe

Tags: data-cleaning

I've just scraped a dataset of names from a website but the names are coming into the dataframe duplicated. Example:

```
    [MarkMark, SarahSarah, BenBen]
```

The website I'm scraping from has images in the table and it seems like when I've pulled the table into a dataframe format it duplicates the name. How would I go about cleaning this data so I've only got one name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the name string in the middle

```
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda name: name[:len(name)/2])
```